# What about doctrine generated identifiers after persist + flush?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I don't understand a small part of the [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html). Part of the documentation :

> Generated entity identifiers / primary keys are guaranteed to be
>   available after the next successful flush operation that involves the
>   entity in question. You can not rely on a generated identifier to be
>   available directly after invoking persist. The inverse is also true.
>   You can not rely on a generated identifier being not available after a
>   failed flush operation.

Does it mean that if I create an entity which has an auto-generated ID and `persist`+`flush` that entity I can't send the id to an other controller ?

Somethink like :

```
public function testAction()
{
$fabulous = new User();
$fabulousForm = $this->get('form.factory')->create(FabulousType::class, $fabulous);

if($fabulousForm->isSubmitted() && $fabulousForm->isValid())
{
$fabulousId = $fabulousForm->getData()->getUser()->getId();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($fabulous)->flush();

return $this->redirectToRoute('my_fabulous_route', array('user_id' => fabulousId));
}
}
```

Comment: You can use your custom id in another related entity but if you have a problem later flushing your entity with original id your database will be inconsistent and you can get errors. Also there are restrictions if you use doctrine relation mappings between your entities.

Comment: Well the problem is that I want to create a new User, save him and send his Id to another controller sothat I can find the User that I've just saved in the second controller and do some stuff with him.

Comment: If performance is not a problem you can first flush your user entity to database and get again user entity from database with real id. There are at least 2 queries.

Answer (score 1):

> You can not rely on a generated identifier **being not available** after a **failed** flush operation.

So, not really, if your `flush` has completed successfully, your ID will be available and can be used safely.

One exception to this is when transaction is being used. If I am not mistaken, the `flush` will also create a valid ID, but failing to commit a transaction properly results in record being removed.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Ok so I think that I can use send the ID to another controller with minimal risk of fail. Hvala !